# how to realistically load website url on a glitch.com nodejs linux operating server

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm

glitch.com allows you to load server side nodeJS for free
I need to find a node package that works with glitch that allows me to run/load websites from a url.

The past few days I have been trying absolutely everything to resolve this issue.
I have tried open, openurl, puppeteer, chrome, executable lines.

I'm pretty sure glitch nodejs servers use xdg-open and run on linux.

I have tried most nodejs packages.

I need to be able to run any website without cors errors, and run the client side js of the website realistically, allowing redirects, requests, etc that a normal browser can do.